# My change-nickname command suddenly isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I had this change nickname command that worked perfectly up until a few days ago, and I've been trying to figure out why it's not working, but I can't find what's wrong. Here is my code:

```
    @commands.command(aliases=['chnick'])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def change_nick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, nick):

        await member.edit(nick=nick)
        await ctx.send(f"Nickname for {member.mention} has been changed to {nick}")
```

Comment: What intents have you enabled?

Comment: Statements like "it's not working" aren't helpful; there could be any conceivable reason as to why it's not working. It would help us be able to help you if you included any error messages. Though if I had to guess, as @ŁukaszKwieciński is hinting at, your bot is probably not "seeing" the user you're attempting to modify due to missing gateway intents. Relevant: [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#intents) and [Discord docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents)

Comment: This is a helpful explanation of Discord's gateway intents from the perspective of discord.py: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Comment: I'm so dumb. apparently it wasn't working because I was testing it on someone who had the same highest role as my bot lol. Thank you for your help though!!

Answer (score 1):

You need your intents turned on in your bot's page.
Here is a [picture](https://i.ibb.co/6m16VpQ/Screenshot-4.png) that shows how to do so.

After enabling intents, you have to get the intents.

This is how you get intents on your code.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix intents=intents)
```

I hope this helped best of luck on your bot.

Comment: I already had Intents enabled and I realized that my bot just didn't have the right permissions for some reason. Thank you for your help though!!